# Cypress MySql cy.task('queryDb') failed with the following error: > connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3036

Tags: mysql, automation, automated-tests, cypress

The next code gives the next error in cypress while trying to execute a query in mysql server:

cy.task('queryDb') failed with the following error:

> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3036

From Node.js Internals:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3036
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)

File: cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const mysql = require('mysql')

const db = {
        'host': '127.0.0.1',
        "port":'3036',
        "user":"root",
        "password":"password",
        'database':'db_name'
    }

function queryTestDb(query, config) {
// creates a new mysql connection using credentials from cypress.json env's
const connection = mysql.createConnection(db);
// start connection to db
connection.connect();
// exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
connection.query(query, (error, results) => {

  if (error) reject(error);
  else {
    connection.end();
    // console.log(results)
    return resolve(results);
  }
  });
  });
  }



module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {

setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

  on('task',{

    queryDb: query => {
  return queryTestDb(query, config);
    }
  })
  // implement node event listeners here
  // implement node event listeners here

},
specPattern: "cypress/e2e/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
},
});
```

this happens when try to run the next test

```
it('Create a Table', function () {
    cy.task('queryDb', 
        {query:"CREATE TABLE Persons (PersonID int, FirstName varchar(255), Address varchar(255), City varchar(255))"})
    })
```